# can't import bootstrap css using site.com platform

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, import, salesforce

I'm trying to implement bootstrap through site.com/salesforce platform, but when importing the css, I can import both bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css, but bootstrap-responsive and bootstrap-responsive.min fail because, according to site.com, "Error: The CSS code can't be saved because it isn't formed correctly. Ensure the code doesn't contain invalid characters, such as mismatched or missing brackets, and try again".

I think it's because of the "@"s in the css like, for example, the "@-ms-viewport", but I fail to find a solution for this. Would be grateful for any sort ideas to solve this.

Comment: `min` in the file name shows that this file is minified, so `bootstrap.min.css` is the minified version of `bootstrap.css` and you shouldn't include both of them. `@-ms-viewport` is not a valid css syntax but I guess there are bunch of these selectors in bootstrap.css too. Please link us to the files you are trying to import.

Comment: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ it's the files in the css folder, ok thanks for telling me the minified thing, still can't upload bootstrap-responsive.css though, it has those selectors also.

Comment: :( guess I'm stuck in this one, thanks for anyone who read anyway.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround for this is to import the css file as a document, and choose not to convert it to css:

[image: Do not convert into style sheets]

You'll be able to add the stylesheet in the template/page setup area like normal:
[image: Select the stylesheet as normal]

One downside to this is that the styles will not be pulled into the page editor. However, they are fully functional on the user side.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can import stylesheets with @-webkit-[x] elements into Site.com. The problem is probably somewhere else. I've seen it happen when there was a missing semicolon that other CSS validators had missed.  I think the Site.com import tool is being more strict than the other tools you're used to.

While importing is easier when you've got a well-formed stylesheet, you can create an empty stylesheet in the Site.com editor. While you're editing that style sheet, you'll see a button labeled "Edit Style Sheet Code"; if you hit that button, you'll have an editor dialog that you can paste your existing style sheet into piecemeal. Make sure you paste in full blocks--you'll need to have the full definition of any style items you paste in, including the closing bracket.

You can "Quick Save" the style sheet as you incrementally paste in your existing style sheet, and when it fails to save you'll have found the poorly formed block of CSS. You'll probably see the error in that block and be able to fix it easily--if not, you could omit it or create a new style item of the same name with the same properties through the normal stylesheet editing process.

Either way, you can continue incrementally pasting in your style sheet until you've got a fully valid stylesheet loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I did what David Scruggs suggested and pasted segments of the bootstrap.css into the Site.com editor.  I was successful pasting in all the css selectors except the following--

```
.carousel-control.left {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, color-stop(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0%), color-stop(rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 100%));
  background-image:         linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#80000000', endColorstr='#00000000', GradientType=1);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.carousel-control.right {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, color-stop(rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 0%), color-stop(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%));
  background-image:         linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#80000000', GradientType=1);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
@-ms-viewport {
  width: device-width;
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

We have noticed a similar issue importing a custom css file into site.com and it appears to be the `calc` tag. Ex:`width: calc(50% - 30px);`

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, have you been able to import a style sheet with calc? We are actively trying now and are unable to. I would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: No, I have never used SalesForce. This post came up in the "new users" review queue and I simply fixed some minor formatting.